# SharePoint add-in to works in conjunction with Dynamics app?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-365, office-store

I'm building a solution that integrates **Dynamics 365** and **SharePoint Online**.
I have two packages: **SharePoint add-in** and **Dynamics 365 app (managed solution)**.
My plan is to submit the SharePoint add-in to the AppSource Store and describe that the SharePoint add-in works in conjunction with other add-in (Dynamics 365 app) that is available from the provider. The Dynamics app creates Application user and in this way I' able to achieve server-to-server (S2S) authentication.

**My question is - is this approach allowed by the AppSource policy?**

My understanding of [5.9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies#5-apps-and-add-ins-put-the-customer-in-control) and [this post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/combining-store-add-ins-with-high-trust-permissions/) is that the described scenario is not against the policies which means - it is allowed.
I highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed by the AppSource policy a SharePoint add-in to work in conjunction with Dynamics 365 app. I just got approval of my [add-in](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381688?src=stackoverflow&tab=Overview).